# how to automatically set the value of maximum property of vertical scrollbar depending on a panel's height

Tags: vb.net

This is how it goes:

I added a vertical scroll bar on a panel which is panel1 and inside panel1 I also Added another panel which is panel2.

The height of panel2 is bigger than panel1, this is where vscrollbar comes in...I already added the code for vscrollbar so that it will change the location of panel2 inside panel1.
The auto size function of panel2 is set to true so that it will automatically grow to fit the controls that i put inside it, which is why panel2 is bigger than panel1. How can I set the maximum property of vscrollbar depending on the height of panel2, I already have an idea of getting the height of panel2 and manipulate the numbers and add it to the maximum property of vscrollbar, the problem is I dont know how to do it.....I know other people will tell me why not just set the auto scroll property of panel1 to true... I already know about that too...I just want learning experience and for other future purposes...I'm a beginner and still learning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Handle the SizeChanged event of the Panel, get its Height property, process as required and assign the result to the Maximum of the VScrollBar.  Similarly for the Width and Maximum of an HScrollBar.